# mypy case exhaustion in pattern matching over parameters of `@overload`ed function

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching, overloading, mypy, python-typing

I have a Python class `MyClass`, with three acceptable ways to instantiate it:

- directly using a `BitVector`;
- using an `int` and a `bytes` representing the size and the content of a bit vector;
- using an `int` and a `str` representing the size and the content of a bit vector.

Using type annotations, in particular the `@overload` decorator, I make sure that the constructor cannot be misused.
On top of that, to make sure I don't forget any cases, I implement an exhaustive pattern matching.

Altogether, it looks like the following:

```py
from typing import overload, NoReturn, Optional, Union

def assert_never(value: NoReturn) -> NoReturn:
    assert False, f'Unhandled value: {value} ({type(value).__name__})'

class BitVector(): ...

class MyClass:

    @overload
    def __init__(self, *, size: int, content: bytes): ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, *, size: int, content: int): ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self, *, bv: BitVector): ...

    def __init__(self, bv: Optional[BitVector]=None, size: Optional[int]=None, content: Optional[Union[bytes,int]]=None):
        if isinstance(size, int) and isinstance(content, (bytes, int)):
            # instanciate a BitVector and do something
            ...
        elif isinstance(bv, BitVector):
            # do something with it
            ...

        else:
            assert_never((bv, size, content))
```

However, when running `mypy`, I get the following error:

```
example.py:25: error: Argument 1 to "assert_never" has incompatible type "Tuple[None, Optional[int], Union[bytes, int, None]]"; expected "NoReturn"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

It's as if `mypy` was only relying on the signature of the implementation function, without considering the type constraints declared by the `@overload`s...

How can I perform an exhaustive pattern matching over the only combinaisons of types the parameters can take, as declared by the `@overload` declarations?

Answer (score -1):

You should not add signature to the real def function:

```
@overload
def __init__(self, *, size: int, content: Union[bytes, int]): ...

@overload
def __init__(self, *, bv: BitVector): ...

def __init__(self, *, bv=None, size=None , content=None):
```

I added * to the real def to follow overload signature.

Comment: This does not answer the question, because "pattern matching exhaustion" is not enforced anymore:
If I put `assert_never((bv, size, content))` as the sole body of the implementation function, `mypy` does not show any error, which is a problem!

Comment: In the `@overload` signatures, `*` is present to signal that the following arguments are keyword arguments. This is not necessary in the "real" definition, as all arguments are keyword arguments, because they receive a default value.

Comment: My bad. I did not understood the question.